# jQuery 'shake' function display error

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-animate

I built a simple random question generator here: http://jsfiddle.net/thevenin/hddMV/

For some reason, when the error message appears and shakes on the screen, it sometimes leaves a black bar on the right side of the display. This problem occurs randomly, and disappears randomly as well. What is causing this issue?

I apologize in advance for my unprofessional coding >.<

Comment: Can you give us screenshot of this?

Comment: Any particular browser/OS this happens on?

Comment: I think it has nothing to do with the shake function itself but with something like your browser displays this effect. Have you tried it on different browsers or another computer?

Comment: Here is a screenshot: http://imgur.com/aC053
It's a minor issue, but it's still annoying.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've had this problem in chrome too, it seems to be a browser rendering bug.

Here is a solution. That is to call

```
$('#background').fadeOut(0,function() {$('#background').fadeIn(0); } );
```

after the animation is done, to refresh the display as alt-tab in and out of the browser or changing tabs removes the line.

To make the order correct I changed the code so that each animation happens when the one prior has completed its run.

http://jsfiddle.net/hddMV/7/

Comment: I think your method works, but a couple questions: 1. Is this a chrome issue only? 2. Is there a way to refresh after all of the animations finish? Thanks!

Comment: yeah, http://jsfiddle.net/hddMV/8/ since you loop twice we can check the loop is in the end "if (i==2) {}" to make the refresh. I can't speak with absolute certainty but I've not encountered this bug using firefox. Safari might share the issue since both safari and chrome use webkit.